# IE script source load issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have written some javascript functions and saved the file as `dashboardjs.jsp`. The reason why the file is made as jsp is that i wanted to use struts2 tag inside the scripts. Now i call this script in a script tag as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dashboardjs.jsp"></script>
```

After loading this script i am just trying to call a function in the above script on load

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
   $(function(){
    getTrend(id,true,false); //this function is defined in dashboardjs.jsp
   });
</script>
```

The above works completely fine in FF,Chrome but in IE it throws error saying getTrend is undefined. In IE developer tool (network tab) it shows that the call to the script `dashboardjs.jsp` is made multiple times. My question is why IE is behaving in this way? Is there any solution for this problem? Please suggest.

Comment: can you rename `dashboardjs.jsp` to `dashboardjs.js` and try again ?

Comment: mime type issue associated with jsp file extension maybe? Not sure how safe it is to do this, but maybe adding a second mime type for .jsp as application/x-javascript. Note: I do not recommend doing this permanently but it would determine if this is the issue.

Comment: I've just done a test and it appears that internet explorer will not inherit the mime type set as `text/javascript` in the script tag if it doesn't match the server response.